# Common neighborhood property

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

First of all, I will introduce some notations:
$N(v)$ denotes the neighbourhood of a vertex $v$ in a graph and $e(B,C)$ denotes the number of orderes pairs $(b,c)$, where $b \in B$, $c \in C$ and and $bc$ is an edge on $G$. Let $X$ be an unspecified subset of vertices and $Y$ be the set of all neighbors of $v$ in $G$.

I cannot understand the following
\begin{equation}
\sum_{u\in X}|N(u) \cap N(v)| = e(X,Y).
\end{equation}

My problem is, that $X \neq N(u)$. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What type of graph is $G$?

Comment: $G$ is almost surely $n/2$-regular

Comment: Is it known that $G$ is a simple graph or has other properties?

Comment: Yes, $G$ is simple and it should be a Graph with edge density $1/2$. This means that each two edges are connected with probability $1/2$. The problem is taken from the book "The probabilistic method" from Alon and Spencer. If you are interested in, I can post a link and give page numbers :)

Answer (score 2):

$s(X,Y)$ counts the number of edges between all elements $u$ of $X$ and all elements of $Y=N(v)$, which is exactly the same as counting the number of elements in $N(v)$ that are connected to a specific $u \in X$ and then summing over all $u \in X$, which is exactly what your sum does.

Comment: Tank you! But I am interested in the neighbourhood of $u$, not in the vertices $u \in X$ themselves..

Comment: The neighborhood of $U$ consists exactly of the points that are connected to $u$ by an edge. Hence $|N(u) \cap N(v)|$ counts the number of edges from $u$ to points in $N(v)$.